# My avocado leaves are dying and I don’t know what’s wrong!

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, avocado

[image]I started this avocado almost two years ago. I live in central Wisconsin and this plant is strictly indoors, sometimes if we have a warm gentle rain in summer it will go out. It currently sits in a south facing window with a finger jade, variegated jade, and a thanksgiving cactus. The humidity is at about 50% and the temperature doesn’t dip below 65 degrees Fahrenheit. We have a well and I’ve flushed the soil, so I am pretty sure it’s not salt burn. The leaves were not like this a week ago when I watered it. I just noticed it in the past couple of days. I want to know what this could possibly be and what I can do to save my plant and it’s neighbors. The lowest two leaves have dried up about half way and seems to be spreading up the rest of the leaf.

Comment: I wonder if it might be too alkaline.

Comment: How long has it been in that pot? Is it possible it is rootbound or it needs to be repotted in fresh soil?